Find maximum function with 7 variables (REPOST)
My problem was not correctly stated in the old post. (Find maximum function with 7 variables) and because of multiple edits it confuses people.
Here is the function I'm trying to find the maximum:
$$f(x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6,x7)=\frac{(\sum_{i=1}^{7} r_{i}a_{i}x_{i})+\beta}{{(\sum_{i=1}^{7} r_{i}x_{i})+\alpha }} \\ \\
\forall i\in \left\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7 \right\}, x_{i} = n_{i}B \ \wedge \ \ n_{i}\leq n_{i+1} \   (n_{i} \in \left\{1,2,..., S \right\},  B\in \mathbb{N}^{*} )
\\ \\ r_{i},a_{i}, \alpha , \beta, S, B \ constants \ known.
\\ \\ r_{i}, a_{i}, \alpha, S, B > 0 \  always.$$
Given these conditions, the function can also be defined as:
$$ f(n1,n2,n3,n4,n5,n6,n7)=\frac{B(\sum_{i=1}^{7} r_{i}a_{i}n_{i})+\beta}{{B(\sum_{i=1}^{7} r_{i}n_{i})+\alpha }} $$
To find a critical point, let's set partial derivative equals zero, with $\alpha' = \frac{\alpha}{B}$ and $\beta' = \frac{\beta}{B}$
as suggested:
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial n_{j}} = \frac{r_{j}a_{j}((\sum_{i=1}^{7} r_{i}n_{i})+\alpha')-r_{j}((\sum_{i=1}^{7}r_{i}a_{i}n_{i})+\beta')}{((\sum_{i=1}^{7}r_{i}n_{i})+\alpha')^2}=0 \\ \\
\Leftrightarrow  r_{j}a_{j}((\sum_{i=1}^{7} r_{i}n_{i})+\alpha')-r_{j}((\sum_{i=1}^{7}r_{i}a_{i}n_{i})+\beta') = 0 \\ \\
\Leftrightarrow  a_{j}((\sum_{i=1}^{7} r_{i}n_{i})+\alpha')-((\sum_{i=1}^{7}r_{i}a_{i}n_{i})+\beta') = 0 \\ \\
\Leftrightarrow  (\sum_{i=1}^{7} (a_{j}-a_{i})r_{i}n_{i}) = \beta' - a_{j}\alpha'
$$
By identification:
$$
(\sum_{i=1}^{7} r_{i}a_{i}n_{i})=-\beta' \\  (\sum_{i=1}^{7} r_{i}n_{i})=-\alpha'
$$
There is no solution for at least the second equation because of the given conditions ($\alpha′,r_{i},n_{i}>0$
).
I'm stuck. Thanks for your help.
